# ArcoLinux fails to boot from live USB

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, arch-linux

I am trying to install an Arch based distribution, but it seems it doesn't find the device. This is the exact output:

```
::running early hook [udev]
Starting version 247.2-1-arch
::running early hook[archiso_pxe_nbd]
::running hook [udev]
::Triggering uevents...
[      5.4850221 kfd kfd: STONEY not supported in kfd
[      6.8237483 sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[      6.8345402 sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
::running hook {memdisk]
::running hook [archiso_loop_mnt]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_common]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_nbd]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_http]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_nfs]
:: Mounting '/dev/disk/by-label/arcolinuxb-i3-v21.01.7' to ' /run/archiso/boomnt'
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/arcolinuxb-i3-v21.01.7' device did not show up after 30 seconds...
  Falling back to interactive prompt
  You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
sh:can't access tty: job control turned off
```

Could anyone help me to fix this? I really want to run this distro on the machine.

Comment: which motherboard?

Comment: AMD A9 2(4 threads) cores and the GPU is Radeon Graphics. It's a bit old, but runs well on Linux.

Comment: first, did you try all USB ports? It could smth to do with usb2.0/3.0.
second, you can try to disable iommu in bios and add a parameter `iommu=soft` when running liveusb. It's a hint from some not-English forum.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried all the usb ports, all the Arcolinux distros don't work and show the exact same output. Also, Arch works with no problmes and other Arch based distributions with no problem. Anyway I will try the second option of yours.